# Redirección de domino a aplicaciones TCP con distintos puertos pero a misma IP

Tags: nginx, dominio, proxy

La consulta es, si es posible a través de nginx u otro similar, redireccionar un dominio para que se conecte a un puerto interno localizado en el mismo equipo
ej:

```
nombredominiotest => 83.12.a.b:4000 (http o cualquier otro)
aplicación 1 escuchando en: 83.12.a.b:4001
aplicación 2 escuchando en: 83.12.a.b:4002
```

Entonces que desde un cliente realizando una petición del tipo:

```
"aplicacion1.nombredominiotest:4000" -> redirija hacia aplicación 1 en "83.12.a.b:4001"
```

o

```
"aplicacion2.nombredominiotest:4000" -> redirija hacia aplicación 2 en "83.12.a.b:4002"
```

**NOTA:**
Siempre usando nombredominiotest:4000 como puente ya que el 4000 es el único puerto abierto.

Slds!

Comment: Solución publicada en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379663/domain-redirection-to-tcp-applications-with-different-ports-but-to-the-same-ip